# How to run a function for different values at the same time in python?

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to monitor a FTP server.

FTP server has multiple directory and there will be new directory with no pattern. So I am polling the FTP server to emulate monitoring using the following code,

```
import config
import ftplib
import queue
from time import sleep

server = ftplib.FTP()
server.connect(config.ftp_server_address, config.ftp_server_port)
server.login(config.ftp_server_username,config.ftp_server_password)

def change_directory_monitor(dir='./'):
    ls_prev = set()
    while True:
        ls = set(server.nlst(dir))
        add, rem = ls-ls_prev, ls_prev-ls
        if add or rem: yield add, rem
        ls_prev = ls
        sleep(5)

def change_file_monitor(directory):
    ls_prev = set()
    server.cwd(directory)
    while True:
        ls = set(server.nlst())
        add, rem = ls-ls_prev, ls_prev-ls
        if add or rem: yield add, rem
        ls_prev = ls
        sleep(5)

root_directory = list()
file_queue = queue.Queue()

for added_directory, removed_directory in change_directory_monitor():
    for directory in added_directory:
        root_directory.append(directory)
    try:
        for directory in removed_directory:
            root_directory.remove(directory)
    except:
        pass
    for directory in root_directory:
        print(directory)
        for added_file, removed_file in change_file_monitor(directory): #problem here
            for file in added_file:
                file_queue.put(file)


server.quit()
```

When the program executes the line where the comment "problem here", it stays inside the for loop and never leaves because the function constantly pools the FTP directory for file changes.

I want to poll all the FTP directory for file changes while monitoring root directory for additional directory. Is it possible to use the directories in `root_directory` and `change_file_monitor` function in program to run in parallel to monitor the FTP directories?

Or do I have to manually run a python program for each and every directory?

Comment: You do not have to run that in parallel. Just monitor every folder sequentially in a loop.

Comment: Monitoring is a continuous process. To monitor, for example, four directory, I have to continuously poll the first directory for changes. So it is a never end loop that never goes past the first sequence (to monitor the first directory). How do I do it sequentially? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: I've meant that you get poll directory 1, then 2, then 3, ... N and then back to 1.

Comment: I see. I can definitely do that but the time taken will increase based on new directory creations. I want to emulate real-time monitoring so threading is the only option I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating programs as follows:

1. For every new directory in FTP server, create a python file that monitors the new directory
2. For every deleted directory, delete the existing python file.
3. The created/deleted python files will be in a separate folder called 'Monitor_FTP_directory'
4. A python script monitors the directory for file changes, if a new file comes in, i.e., a python script that monitors a FTP directory, it runs the new file.

This is the most inefficient way of doing it but it was a quick fix.